# Screen not centered on the monitor

Tags: screen

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and my screen is somehow not centered. Its moved one or two inch to the right of the monitor. I only see half of shutdown, restart, switch user options(luckily I see enough to shutdown computer).

Comment: auto-adjust button on your monitor?

Comment: tried that didn't help. I think its problem in nvidia drivers. I have option to install aditional drivers but there are 4 versions of nvidia drivers listed and I don't know which to activate(8600 GT)

Comment: nvidia-current? It says the complete list of supported GPUs is in /usr/share/doc/nvidia-current/README.txt.gz, so you can try to install it and then check that file.

Comment: i manually installed latest nvidia drivers(nvidia x-server say version 295.49) but still have same problem

Comment: problem solved, didn't remove old drivers, now it works

Comment: You should post an answer and accept it to mark this as solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The OP reported in comments that he had not removed the old drivers before installing the new Nvidia drivers, and that removing the old drivers solved the problem.